# Hour and minutes in one column in R

Tags: r

I'd like to separate hour and minute in another column. But, don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance!
Actual format:

```
TIME
20:16:38
20:38:31
21:21:47
21:27:07
21:33:50
21:48:50
22:06:43
```

Comment: ?strsplit, strsplit(TIME,split=":")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the values provided a solution might be:

```
TIME <- c("20:16:38", "20:38:31", "21:21:47", "21:27:07", "21:33:50", "21:48:50", "22:06:43")
timeMat <- t(sapply(1:length(TIME), function(x) {
          unlist(strsplit(TIME[x], ":"))
        })
        )
timeMat[,c(1,2)]
```

The last object contains the two columns you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

If `type` of `TIME` is `character`:

```
# hour
substr(TIME,1,2)
# minute
substr(TIME,4,5)
```

Comment: I need the hour and minutes values as integer, to consolidate them.

Comment: @helio7sr You can convert like `as.numeric(substr(TIME,4,5))`